# Using IN operator on a correlated subquery

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

Consider the following query on the two following Tables:

```
SELECT sid FROM Salesman SM WHERE sid IN(SELECT sid FROM Sale S WHERE s.sid<>sm.sid)
```

Sale Table

```
SALEID  SID SLDATE
1001    1   01-Jan-14
1006    1   01-Jun-15
1003    4   01-Feb-14
1002    5   02-Jan-14
1005    2   01-Feb-14
1004    1   01-Mar-14
```

Salesman Table

```
SID SNAME   LOCATION
1   Peter   London
2   Michael Paris
3   John    Mumbai
5   Kevin   London
4   Harry   Chicago
6   Alex    Chicago
```

Why it doesn't fetch any results?

For example: on the first iteration of outer query, inner query should return 2,4,5. But it seems not. Why?

PS: Please ignore the practical use of such a query. This is for academic purpose.

Comment: Because you say "you want a row if sid is in (any sid except this one)"

Comment: are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is impossible to fetch anything with this condition, I don't understand what you were trying to do..
As I see it you either meant to select all the sailsmans that didn't make any sales, and in that case this is the right query:

```
select sid from Salesman SM where sid not in (select sid from Sale S)
```

or you want only the salesmans that did make a sale, and in that case this is the right query:

```
select sid from Salesman SM where sid in (select sid from Sale S)
```

Comment: I was trying neither. I was just trying to see what was wrong with what I have written. And I got it. As mentioned the query was not written for practical purpose, but just for academic interest.